# How to shuffle array questions?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm just new to C++. Can someone help me randomized this questions when I cout? Is there a way to randomize this?

I have this code. Can someone tell me how to randomize these?

```
string questionpart[20]={"What is the square root of 4?",
                            "What is the square root of 6?",
                            "What is the square root of 16?",
                            "What is the square root of 25?",
                            "What is the square root of 36?",
                            "What is the square root of 42?",
                            "What is the square root of 48?",
                            "What is the square root of 81?",
                            "What is the square root of 100?",
                            "What is the square root of 121?",
                            "What is the square root of 144?",
                            "What is the square root of 169?",
                            "What is the square root of 196?",
                            "What is the square root of 225?",
                            "What is the square root of 256?",
                            "What is the square root of 289?",
                            "What is the square root of 324?",
                            "What is the square root of 361?",
                            "What is the square root of 400?",
                            "What is the square root of 1?",
                            };

string partans[20]={"2",
                        "3",
                        "4",
                        "5",
                        "6",
                        "7",
                        "8",
                        "9",
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12",
                        "13",
                        "14",
                        "15",
                        "16",
                        "17",
                        "18",
                        "19",
                        "20",
                        "1"};
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: create an array of indexes (0-19) and use a `rand` function for shuffle its values. Then answers and questions will not be lost their links

Comment: You should probably use a calculator and double-check your questions and answers.

Comment: You can use [std::shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/). Also it seems you have a misprint in the second line. Must be "square root of 9" instead of "square root of 6". And there is the same problem with 42 and 48 (must be 49 and 64).

Comment: TBH you are much better off scrapping this plan and generating a random answer,, and then generate the number for the question based on the answer.

Comment: @M.M , yes, it is first modification we want to do after reading of this code. But it is possible that this change will be wrong. For instance, in a case when this code will be used for geographical tests too (i.e. it will be impossible to generate quastions and answers automatically from numbers).

Answer (score 1):

you can create a vector of indexes and use for it the `std::shuffle`

also you can use half-manual shuffling. Example:

```
srand(time(NULL));
rand();

unsigned indexes[cnt];
unsigned fact = 0;

while(fact < cnt)
{
    const unsigned r = rand() % cnt;
    bool was = false;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < fact; ++i)
    {
        if(indexes[i] == r) {
            was = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!was)
    {
        indexes[fact] = r;
        ++fact;
    }
}

for(unsigned i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
{
    const unsigned j = indexes[i];
    cout << "Q: " << questions[j] << "; A: " << answers[j] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment on the question you can use the [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) from [cstdlib](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/) and to limit the returned random number, use a [modulus(%)](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html).

```
srand(time(NULL));
index = rand() % array_size;
```

then use the that index to access the question in the array.

```
cout << questionpart[index] << endl;
```

EDIT: you may need to use the [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) for the srand

EDIT2: to randomize without repeating the same question, you may have to store the questions that were already used to keep track of it or simply remove it totally from the array if you don't need it anymore.

for a more advanced approach you can define an object that will hold everything (the question, answer, and state)
something like:

```
class Question {
    string question;
    string answer;
    bool wasAsked = false;
}
```

then create an array out of it(or preferably [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for dynamic array support)

```
Question questions[array_size];
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this it says I didn't declare array_size and index. Do you have any idea why is that? Thanks!

Comment: This may end up printing a question more than once though - my understanding of 'shuffling' is that you ask each question at most once, but in a random order.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe That's what I wanted. Any idea how I would do that instead of printing more than once?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe not particularly stated in the original question, but to solve that, you may use another array to keep track of questions that have been used.

Comment: there are really a lot of other ways to solve this depending on what's easier for you to understand